# Arduino Uno WiFi data storage after refresh

Tags: arduino, webserver, wifi

I am currently experimenting with implementing a WiFi based communication display with a piezoelectric based scoring target.

The target hardware works as intended at this early stage with different analog pins serial printing different scores when they sense an impact.

I am trying to translate the `serial.print` to `client.print` using the Arduino webserver template, but my printed data is removed after each refresh. Is there a way to store

```cpp
client.println(" your score is ");
client.println(score);
```

without using SQL and PHP?

I have attached the code section, with the original template, in question below.

```cpp
void WebServer(WifiData client) {
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Refresh: 0.5");  // refresh the page automatically every    
    client.println();
    client.println("<html>");
    client.println("<head> <title>Auto Target v0.2</title> </head>");
    client.print("<body>");

    for(int analogChannel = 0; analogChannel < 1; analogChannel++) {
        int sensorReading = analogRead(analogChannel);
        client.print("analog input ");
        client.print(analogChannel);
        client.print(" is ");
        client.print(sensorReading);
        client.print("<br/>");

        val = analogRead(analogPin1);
        if(val > threshold) {

            client.println("Hit 1!");
            score = score + 5;

            if (score >= 100) {
                client.println("Congrats! You Scored 100 POINTS!");
            }
            client.print("YOUR SCORE ");
            client.println(score);

            delay (800);
        }
```

Comment: why the android tag?

Comment: One solution is to write data into file storage as simple key-value pairs.

Comment: I've done some tinkering with the order, placing the client.print of the score before the  for loop and then omitting the for loop completely is close to what I was aiming for, yet the client.print is still removed after each refresh. The total score is stored however.

Comment: Wasn't too sure with the android tag myself, as the webserver is running from an android device with the final goal to be pulling the webserver data into an android app

Comment: In php when you run a sever side script the scope of each variable is per process, and by default a new process is created to handle each client request take a look at http request https://abhinavsingh.com/how-does-php-echos-a-hello-world-behind-the-scene/

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment so I can't ask questions and must write an answer.

You set refresh 0.5 in the http header. Refresh header is undocumented, but usually the number is seconds. I do not know if decimals are allowed there. If it would be a half of a second, you have a delay(800) in your code. Do not know what will be the outcome of this. Maybe a page refresh before complete load.

The connection between Atmega and ESP8266 on Uno WiFi with factory firmware is 9600 baud and it slows down data streams to and from network. It is an other reason for page not loading to end before refresh.

Your code is cut and we can't see if you close the html tags.